# How to print an object in Golang template like if we could have done in JavaScript

Tags: go

```
renderTemplate(w, "index", map[string]interface{}{
    "ActualQAll": req.URL.Query(),
})
```

and inside golanghtml

```
...{{.ActualQAll}}...
```

But it shows nothing.

how can I print the whole object out like if I could do in JavaScript by doing JSON.stringify(obj) an object?

Comment: If you want to print it as json, you need to marshal it into json. The template package won't do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use fmt.Sprintf function, maybe something like below:

```
renderTemplate(w, "index", fmt.Sprintf("%s", ActuallQAll))
```

I'm not sure what exactly the object looks like.